# rendering alternate components under the same flow:router URL

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, spacebars, flow-router

How can I render two different views in a one page app without changing URLs. I'm using meteor with the default blaze as well as the flow:router package. Right now I have it set up like this:
routes.js..

```
FlowRouter.route("/", {
  name: "App.home",
  action() {
    BlazeLayout.render("App_body", {
      main: "App_home",
      mainContent: "calendar"
    });
  }
});

FlowRouter.route("/list", {
  name: "App.list",
  action() {
    BlazeLayout.render("App_body", { main: "App_home", mainContent: "list" });
  }
});
```

but this way I'm using the url /list and i dont want that. I would like to simply render an alternate component template in the same url. I'm very new to coding so forgive me if this is obvious. Essentially I just want two different view styles: a list and a calendar. So I would like a way to set it up so that a spacebars template can be rendered if a certain button is clicked, and a different one can be rendered instead if another button is clicked.

Thanks so much for any help, i've been at this for a couple of days :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle this within a single template like so:

```
FlowRouter.route('/', {
  name: 'App.home',
  action() {
  BlazeLayout.render('App_body', { main: 'App_home', mainContent: 'ListOrCalendar' });
}
```

And then the `ListOrCalendar` template would look like this:

```
{{#if displayList}}
  {{> List}}
{{else}}
  {{> Calendar}}
{{/if}}
<button>Switch</button>
```

You would set up a `ReactiveVar` in the `ListOrCalendar` template:

```
Template.ListOrCalendar.onCreated(function() {
  const instance = this;
  instance.displayList = new ReactiveVar(true);
});
```

See `ReactiveVar` explanation [here](https://themeteorchef.com/tutorials/reactive-dict-reactive-vars-and-session-variables) (ignore Session)

Then you would have a helper which returns the value of your ReactiveVar:

```
Template.ListOrCalendar.helpers({
  displayList() {
    const instance = Template.instance();
    return instance.displayList.get();
  }
});
```

Finally, you would hook up an event to change the value of `displayList` to switch between templates:

```
Template.ListOrCalendar.events({
  "click button"(event, instance) {
    const displayListCurrent = instance.displayList.get();
    const displayListNew = !displayListCurrent;
    instance.displayList.set(displayListNew);
    // or, more concisely, instance.displayList.set(!instance.displayList.get());
  }
});
```

So, in summary:

- When the template is created, your `ReactiveVar` is `true`

  - so your `displayList` returns `true`
  - so the `#if displayList` condition in the template is satisfied
  - and so the `List` template is displayed
- When the button is clicked

  - The `ReactiveVar` is set to false
  - so the `displayList` helper returns `false`
  - so the `#if displayList` condition in the template is *not* satisfied and it goes to the `else` statement
  - and so, finally, the `Calendar` template is displayed
- When the button is clicked again, the `ReactiveVar` is toggled back to `true`, and on we go as above

This might seem daunting or over-complicated, but there's nothing fancy going on here at all. You'll get used to it pretty quickly

Comment: This is beautiful. I can understand it and it looks nice and elegant. I'll implement it a bit later and let you know how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: I think you might have accidentally switched your naming convention for "displayList" to "listSelected". I switched everything to displayList and the whole thing worked like a charm. Thanks so much!

Comment: Good catch! Corrected

Answer (score 2):

Create another template, which renders particular view conditionally. Something like this:

```js
FlowRouter.route("/", {
  name: "App.home",
  action() {
    BlazeLayout.render("App_body", {
      main: "App_home",
      mainContent: "listOrCal"
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<template name="listOrCal">
  {{#if showList}}
    {{> list}}
  {{else}}
    {{> calendar}}
  {{/if}}
  <button id="switchView">Switch view</button>
</template>
```

```js
Template.listOrCal.onCreated(function listOrCalOnCreated() {
  this.showList = new ReactiveVar(true);
})

Template.listOrCal.helpers({
  showList() {
    return Template.instance().showList.get();
  }
})

Template.listOrCal.events({
  'click #switchView' {
    let showList = Template.instance().showList.get();
    Template.instance().showList.set(!showList);
  }
})
```

Comment: Haha - I think your answer got there 2 mins faster than mine! They're *exactly* the same - hooray for standard practices!